# How to simplify code that has a lot if statement and how to change image faster

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

just two simple questions,

Q(1) the below code has multiple if else statement I wanna know if there is a way to simplify this using array or something else.

Q(2)is there a way to change bgImg.src faster because it takes a little bit longer to change the src.

```
const bgImg = document.querySelector('#element-body img');
let icon = "";

if(weatherName.includes("rain")){
           icon = "./images/rain.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName.includes("clouds")){
           icon = "./images/clouds.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName.includes("snow")){
           icon = "./images/snow.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "mist"){
           icon = "./images/mist.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "clear sky"){
           icon = "./images/clear-sky.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "smoke"){
           icon = "./images/smoke.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "dust"){
           icon = "./images/dust.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "drizzle"){
           icon = "./images/rain.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "haze"){
           icon = "./images/haze.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "fog"){
           icon = "./images/foggy.jpg";
        }
        else if(weatherName === "thunderstorm"){
           icon = "./images/thunderstorm.jpg";
        }
        else{
           icon = "./images/pexels-photo-39811.jpg";
        }
      }
     bgImg.src = icon;
    }
```

Comment: Don't ask two different questions in one. And writing `I asked this question before but the answered code doesn't work with me` without mentioning which question it was, is not a nice idea, why should I take the time to answer that question if i don't know what the other answers have been.

Comment: That doesn't seem that complicated. Why do you feel it need simplifying? It seems pretty "simple" as it is. What makes you think this block of code is "inefficent"? This is going to take a tiny, tiny fraction of a second to calculate using virtually no CPU. It's really not clear why your so against this piece of code?

Comment: @Liam i'm not against this code i just wanna know if there is better way to do same operation with less code

Comment: @ t.niese thanx for the advise

Comment: Probably not. To quote Donald Kuth *"Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."* Stop wasting time on a non critical part of your system

Comment: @Liam The problem is not execution speed, the problem is duplicated code.

Comment: @Bergi OP asks `is there a way to change bgImg.src faster`

Comment: @Liam Ah, I ignored the second question...

Comment: @ Liam the reason why i asked how to load bgImg faster is that when API makes a new request the image is not loading faster it takes 1 or 2 seconds to change the image src and I think that is not a good performance that's why am asking.

Comment: That is nothing to do with this code. Thats how long the image takes to be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

You could take tow arrays for part string check with includes and for an exact check and return a find with replaced spaces.

```js
const getIcon = weather => {
    var includes = ['rain', 'clouds'],
        exact = ['snow', 'mist', 'clear sky', 'smoke', 'dust', 'drizzle', 'haze', 'fog', 'thunderstorm'],
        type = includes.find(w => weather.includes(w)) ||
               exact.includes(weather) && weather ||
              'pexels-photo-39811';

    return `./images/${type.replace(/\s/g, '-')}.jpg`;
};

console.log(getIcon('some rain'));
console.log(getIcon('clear sky'));
console.log(getIcon('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays separated by the method you need to compare the string and loop through the icon lists. If you need to modify the lists, you can just do it in the arrays.

```
const bgImg = document.querySelector('#element-body img');
const iconListInclude = [
  'rain',
  'clouds',
  'snow',
]
const iconListEqual = [
  'mist',
  'clear sky',
  'smoke',
  'dust',
  'drizzle',
  'haze',
  'fog',
  'thunderstorm',
]
let icon = "./images/pexels-photo-39811.jpg"
iconListInclude.forEach(i => {
  if (weatherName.includes(i)) icon = "./images/"+i+".jpg"
})
iconListEqual.forEach(i => {
  if (weatherName === i) icon = "./images/"+i+".jpg"
})
bgImg.src = icon
```

Comment: Note: this will in no way be "faster" than what the OP already has

Comment: That would match `smoke something` but the condition in the given code is `weatherName === "smoke"`  so it has to be an exact match.

Comment: @t.niese Here I edited it to properly check the conditions and give the correct result.

Comment: I think this is a more complex solution and definitely not faster

Answer (score 0):

You could use an associative array and iterate through the keys to find a match. Sorting the keys in order of the frequency of the weather pattern might speed it up but not significantly.

This snippet replaces spaces in `weatherName` with `-` and changes the string to lower case just to be safe.

```js
const weatherName = "Clear Sky";

const bgImg = document.querySelector('#element-body img');
const localWeather = weatherName.replace(/\s/, '-').toLowerCase();
// Default icon name
let icon = 'pexels-photo-39811';

const iconNames = {
  'clouds': 'clouds',
  'clear-sky': 'clear-sky',
  'drizzle': 'rain',
  'dust': 'dust',
  'fog': 'foggy',
  'haze': 'haze',
  'mist': 'mist',
  'rain': 'rain',
  'snow': 'snow',
  'smoke': 'smoke',
  'thunderstorm': 'thunderstorm',
}

for (let key of Object.keys(iconNames)) {
    if (localWeather.includes(key)) {
        icon = iconNames[key];
        // Icon found so exit the `for()` loop
        break;
    }
}

bgImg.src = `./images/${icon}.jpg`;
```

```html
<div id="element-body">
  <img id="weather-icon" src="" title="Local weather" />
</div>
```

In answer to part 2 of your question swapping the image `src` attribute's value is faster than creating a new element. If it appears to be slow then it's a web server performance issue.

An alternative option is to [implement image sprites in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS). If the icon images are concatenated into a single image you can use CSS classes to reveal the correct portion of the image and the new weather icon should appear in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Details are commented on every line in the demo.

**Demo**

```js
/*
Use a block element (ex. <section>...</section>) to contain a 
background image. A block element allows greater control.
*/
const bkg = document.querySelector('.bkg');

/*
Have an array of the images. Use only the unique part of each
url which is usually the file name (ex. ./images/UNIQUE_PART.jpg).
*/
const whiteList = ["rain", "clouds", "snow", "mist", "clear", "smog", "dust", "haze", "fog", "storm"];

// Assuming that API provides an array of strings.
const weatherName = ['crappy', 'crappier', 'level 5', 'flash flooding', "mist", 'smog', 'crappiest', 'swamp ass'];

/*
filterList(array1, array2)
Returns all matches in an array, or an empty array if there are 
no matches.
*/
const filterList = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(ele => arr2.includes(ele));

// Store result in a variable.
const icon = filterList(whiteList, weatherName);

/* 
If there was no match [?] use the default image file name [:]
Otherwise use the first image file name of the returned array.
*/
let image = icon === [] ? `pexels-photo-39811` : icon[0];

/*
Interpolate image file name into a Template Literal that consists
of the common part of the url.
*/
const url = `https://i.ibb.co/y4Ctj4p/${image}.jpg`;

/* 
Assign the CSS style property backgroundImage to the [style]
attribute of the block element. There are 2 reasons why [style]
attribute is used:
  1. Using the [style] attribute is the simplest way to style any 
     DOM element.
  2. It's nigh impossible to override it and it overrides
     everything so there's no suprises.
*/
bkg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Verdana;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.bkg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<main class='bkg'></main>
```